# Unable to read data from CLI

Tags: c#, command-line-interface

I have a program which is connected to ST-Link. At the moment you can select a firmware from a combo box, press start and it will program the firmware onto the circuit board connected to the ST-LInk.

To do this, I use a CLI to send commands to the ST-Link using ST-LINK_CLI.exe. Once the firmware is programmed on, it comes up on the command prompt: "run application to exit". Here the user presses enter, and the application runs on the board and the CLI exits.

However, what I need it to do is to not have the prompt where the user presses enter, and to just automatically do it.

My idea to do this was to read the output from the CLI, and figure out what the output is when the user is prompted. I was thinking I could then do a loop, the output data is read in and when it matches the output data when the user has to press enter, I will use SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}").

However, I am having trouble reading the data. The following isn't working:

```
        string STPath = @"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\FalconexTest\FalconexTest\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe";
        string path2 = @"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\FalconexTest\FalconexTest\Firmware\PXL3-DELL-2B.SREC";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = STPath;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ME -p " + firmwareLocation + " -v -Run ";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.WaitForExit();

        while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {

            string line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            File.WriteAllText("New.txt", line);

        }
```

The following is the error message that comes up:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll and points to the end of stream part.

I was wondering if anyone knew why this was happening? Or if there is another way around the prompt issue?

Thanks 
Lucy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not have been the best way to do this, but to get it to exit without the user and still run, I just sent the enter key to it constantly until it exited.

```
 while (process.HasExited == false)
                {
                    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
                }
```

Comment: Is this a busy loop? If it is, it may be a good idea to add a "sleep" call (for 50 milliseconds, perhaps) in order to limit the amount of key presses sent and the amount of CPU usage.

Answer (score 1):

If the CLI application is using standard I/O, you can just write to the input stream:

```
p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
```

Also note that when you redirect streams, you *must* read from them. In your case, you only read a single line and then wait for the program to exit. If the program prints out more text that fits in the buffers, you will get a deadlock. Just get rid of the `p.WaitForExit()`, it's pointless and dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the exception because p.BeginOutputReadLine() starts an asynchronous read. This would normally be ended with the handling of the [outputdatareceived](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

However you don't handle this event as such the async event is long running and hasn't finished when the synchronous call to ReadLine() occurs, which is incompatible with the asynchronous read.

I suspect that what you need is to replace your code with something like this:

```
    string STPath = @"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\FalconexTest\FalconexTest\ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK_CLI.exe";
    string path2 = @"C:\Users\Falconex\Documents\FalconexTest\FalconexTest\Firmware\PXL3-DELL-2B.SREC";

    using (Process p = new Process())
    {
        p.StartInfo.FileName = STPath;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-ME -p " + firmwareLocation + " -v -Run ";
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

        p.Start();

        while (!p.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
            if (line == "run application to exit")
            {
                p.StandardInput.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
```